# Exporting epub fixed layout

Tags: epub, indesign, font-rendering

Im trying to export an epub 3.0 from indesign as fixed layout but when I do it, the layout and typefaces are actually changing,.. anybody knows how could I fix this problem... I'm new and about to publish some material but I can't until I fix this...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ePub is just a whole bunch of HTML, some metadata, and CSS. So, you have the same rules as with any HTML page.

1. You can't force any browser to display a page the way you want it. Your "fixed layout" is at best a suggestion.
2. If you specify a typeface, and that typeface is not available on the client device, it will be ignored. You can ensure that the font *is* available by packaging it in your ePub, but you'd better be sure you have a legal right to do so! If you aren't including the font in the ePub, then you have no way to force the client to use it.